# Visual Studio extension project: how to change target Visual Studio version(s)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I'm studying an open-source VS extension project. I've opened and compiled it in my VS2012, but when I launch debugging it opens VS2010. How can I change the target VS version for this extension?

Comment: You opened with VS2012, you compiled it with VS2012 but when you try debug it it close VS2012 and opens VS2010? Are you sure?

Comment: Did you download: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b2fa5b3b-25eb-4a2f-80fd-59224778ea98 instead of http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680?

Comment: @SonerGönül debugging an extension doesn't close VS, it starts a new instance in which the extension is loaded and attaches the current instance's debugger to it. So my guess is the OP's problem is that it launches VS2010 with the extension loaded.

Comment: Is this perhaps an extension project created for VS2010? What's the debugger command line (Project->Properties->Debug) ?

Comment: @stijn Yeah probably. But OP doesn't mentioned the extension part at first revision of his question.

Comment: @stijn: of course VS 2010 path is explicitly specified in the debug settings. Editing that helped, thanks for pointing it out. Please make it an answer so I can upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project is created specifically for VS2010, it might have hardcoded the VS2010 exe path in the debug command line (under Project->Properties->Debug). Change this to invoke VS2012 instead.